# debugging error in xively tutorial for raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, xively

I am new to Raspberry pi and xively and during running the tutorial from xively itself

"https://xively.com/dev/tutorials/pi"

, I had debugging errors as follows:

**"Requirement already up-to-date: xively-python in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages Requirement already up-to-date: requests>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from xively-python) Cleaning up..."**

I guess xivelyAPIs or some other requirements are not installed properly, but I have followed the steps in the mentioned tutorial very carefully and for couple of times from top to bottom. So Im sure that there is nothing I have missed in the tutorial document.

please let me know if anybody knows any solutions to this problem.

Comment: It would be nice if you told us which statement you ran, out of the dozens within that tutorial…

Answer (score 1):

There are no errors in the output you're showing.

If you were trying to install `xively-python`, this means that you already had an up-to-date version of that package, and everything it depends on, so `pip` didn't need to do anything. Which is fine.

If you were trying to install something else, which depends on `xively-python`, it means that `pip` checked `xively-python`, saw that it was up-to-date, and proceeded on to install everything else. Which is also fine.

Either way, there's no problem.

In general, you can tell that `pip` failed if it ends with something like "Storing complete log in /home/foo/.pip/pip.log".

If you need to be absolutely sure that `pip` succeeded, and don't understand the results, you can always follow the `pip` command with this:

```
echo $?
```

`0` means success; `2` means `pip` didn't understand your arguments; anything else (usually `1`) means `pip` got an error.